# Allow sections to spread over pages in book

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, book-design

I am using the template from this [link](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) and I am having a problem so that the spacing after each chapter head is inconsistent as it seems to not allow sections to go over pages. I understand why this would be useful in some cases but for me it makes the chapters look very strange.

When the sections are forced not to be spread over pages it looks as follows:

[image]

But I want it to look like the rest, such as:

[image]

Comment: Please provide an MWE (Code from `\documentclass... to \end{document}` that shows your problem and that we could compile instead of having to guess what you might have done.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by switching to an adaptation of the template found here https://www.overleaf.com/articles/clustering-the-interstellar-medium/mtthgyyfrdkn